# SQLite storage class And retrieval efficiency

Tags: sql, sqlite

Say I have one table, which is a reference table (the table is only been consulted, not update).

for example, the table schema :

```
CREATE TABLE countries(
               zip_code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
               name TEXT)
```

I want to improve the retrieval speed of data. Now, I'm using `index` on the `name`column, but I want to go further...

Change the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE countries(
                   zip_code INT PRIMARY KEY,
                   name CHAR(200))
```

remarque that I've modified the data type of the columns in order to specify a **fixed size for each column, hence a fixed size for the entire row**.

Is it a correct assumption ? Thinking that **fixed size rows** are retrievable more quickly than dynamic size rows **in SQLite DBMS**.

I'm inspiring from other DBMS (MySQL) which retrieve **static size rows** more quickly than dynamic size rows

Comment: Sqlite3 does not force size of a `varchar` column. See https://sqlite.org/faq.html#q9

Comment: You should really only worry about improving the retrieval speed if you've seen that it is too low. For ~200 countries, this almost certainly won't be the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm fixing this answer to be relevant to SQLite.  It is accepted, so I can't delete it.

I don't think that storing 200 bytes for each name is going to speed your query.  In most databases, all it will do is multiply the volume of data you are storing -- because names are shorter.  In SQLite, it is a no-op.  SQLite stores all character strings as text; it does not pad the values with spaces as other databases do.

I am not intimately familiar with the internals of SQLite.  But databases (including SQLite) store records on *data pages*.  These are managed by a caching mechanism.  And indexes identify a record by the page it is on.  The entire data page is read in.

In most databases, declaring a column as `name(200)` would probably waste a lot of space.  It would Increase the size of the record and that has the following effects:

- Fewer records can be store on a single page.
- A subsequent retrieval is less likely to find the page for the record in the cache.
- Reading the entire table is likely to occupy much more memory space.
- Reading a row requires reading and processing more bytes.

In SQLite, none of this applies, because SQLite just ignores the length and doesn't pad the value with spaces.

What you want to do isn't a good idea in most databases, and it has no effect in SQLite.  I would recommend avoiding such an approach.  The index should be sufficient.

Comment: the `countries` table and the `name` column are just examples, I'm more focusing on the **fixed** size of the two columns and the **benefits of using fixed size rows than dynamic size rows**

Comment: @Massy . . . There are basically no benefits for the row as a whole.  Fixed sized index values are beneficial but in your case, multiplying the size of the index is going to completely undermine whatever micro-optimization you might get from fixed-sized keys.

Comment: SQLite _does not have_ fixed-sized records (nor, as @kuro notes, does it limit the size that can be stored). Each record takes as much space as it needs.